# How Do I Get HTML To Bind Properly To An Angular App

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angular app which submits data via json to a PHP application. This application returns to the angular app a response object which has a renderedTable property, and a quote property.

The renderedTable property is batch of HTML text with angular {{expression}}'s within it. Embedded in this table is also `<input>` tags that bind to ng-models in the other mentioned property quote.

Quote is nothing more than a data class, with various properties within it. I am trying to use ng-bind-html in order to get the html code to display (and it does), however, I have 2 issues to work out.

The first issue is that I cannot get the html to properly render, if I use $interpolate I get the values from the quote object, but the `<input>` tag is filtered out (which is necessary), and it's not clear to me that the defined bind points would be dynamic still based on the fact that $interpolate returns a string.

I have tried creating my own unsafe directive, but that has resulted in the same output as with ng-bind-html. How do I get my ajax returned HTML to populate and dynamically update based on the also returned object, AND while keeping all input fields in the page, and bound properly using ng-model?

My code (excerpts):

```
 ...ajax call this is the meat of the function
 if (response.success)
 {
    $scope.crmquote = response.data.crmquote;
    $scope.quoteTable = response.data.crmtable; //this is where I initally applied $interpolate but realized it wasnt what I was looking for
    console.log($scope.quoteTable);
 }

 //this is the function I have setup to try to get angular to "trust" the html and not strip the <input> tags but it doesn tseem to work
 $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
 }

//this is the directive I attempted to use to achieve the desired result
 .directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
           return scope.$eval(attrs.bindUnsafeHtml);
        },
        function(value) {
          element.html(value);
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
 };
 }]);
```

And these are the HTML code snippets I have tried:

```
<div ng-bind-html='to_trusted(quoteTable)' ng-show="editIF == false">
```

```
<div bind-unsafe-html='quoteTable' ng-show="editIF == false">
```

This is the contents of quoteTable:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Description</th><th>Qty</th><th>Rate</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead><tr><td>Monthly Rent for 16'</td><td>1</td><td>$ <input type='text' ng-model='crmquote.rr16'/></td><td>$ {{crmquote.rr16 * crmquote.rr16units | number:2}}</td></tr><tr><td>Initial Delivery</td><td>1</td><td><a href='#' editable-text='crmquote.initialdelivery'>$ {{crmquote.initialdelivery}}</span></td><td>$ {{crmquote.initialdelivery * crmquote.units | number:2}}</td></tr><tr><td>Final Pickup</td><td>1</td><td><span id='editrate'>$ {{crmquote.finalunit}}</span></td><td>$ {{crmquote.finalunit * crmquote.units | number:2}}</td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 style='text-align:right'><b>Sub-Total</b></td><td id='subtotal'>$ {{crmquote.total | number:2}}</td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 style='text-align:right'><b>Taxes (8.50%)</b></td><td id='taxes'>$ {{crmquote.tax | number:2}}</td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 style='text-align:right'><b>Total Due On Delivery</b></td><td id='total'>$ {{crmquote.grandtotal | number:2}}</td></tr></table><br><table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-bottom:0;"><tr><td colspan=2><b>Estimated Future Costs</b></td></tr><tr><td>Additional Monthly Rent for 16' </td><td>$ {{crmquote.rr16 | number:2}} each</td></tr></table>
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your example, but I think your problem is that quoteTable is an object and $sce.TrustAsHtml expects a string.  If I'm right, then you'll need loop through the object and trust each string individually.

Comment: @harper - quoteTable is an html string. Please see my edit.

Comment: `editIF == false`. Just out of curiosity, is that condition evaluating to true?

Comment: Yes. The block is displaying.

Comment: Hmm.  I find it crazy that angular can evaluate angular inside of a random text string.  I use $sce all the time, but have never done that with it.  It doesn't seem like a good separation of concerns (you may want to render the table differently in a few weeks), so if you have control over the API, I'd get a raw json back and render the data from it.

Comment: @harper - its kind of crazy. the $sce for example isnt working in this case, the input tag (see the first row of the first table) is being stripped still, even in the ng-bind-html setup - thats my first problem. The second is getting the expressions to bind and evaluate properly. The reason that the code is relying on server side html is because that HTML can change in structure based on the data that goes in, but the application that inserts values, and calculates totals in angular based on user changes to the input tag which is being stripped. Hope that clarifies a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

```
var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch($sce.parseAsHtml(attr.ngBindHtml), function(value) {
      element.html(value || '');
    });
  };
}];
```

-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#how-does-it-work-

Comment: Yes! the OP have not injected $sce properly!

Comment: Thanks for the post, but SCE is injected properly, and I figured out that I actually had the code binding to the wrong modal (its a complex page). Once I bound it to the rigth modal, the SCE started working perfectly. The issue now is not SCE, but why all of the {{expressions}} remain unbound.